# Can I filter choices for Django models.ForeignKey?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a ManyToMany relationship with models Vehicle and Accounts and an associative entity of Assignment which gets the PKs of both table as FK.

Now the Accounts table has a field of is_driver which takes a Boolean value because by default all accounts are commuters but some can be a Driver.

Is there a way to set my model to filter only Accounts with is_driver == True?

My models.py

```
class Puv(models.Model):
    plate_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    temporary_plate = models.BooleanField(default=True) 
    route = models.ForeignKey(Route, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

class Assignment(models.Model):
    driver = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    puv = models.ForeignKey(Puv, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assignment_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The Users model in a separate app

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ....
    is_driver = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Please share your models.

Comment: I have edited the post and included the models :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**`limit_choices_to=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to):

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    driver = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to={'is_driver': True}
    )
    puv = models.ForeignKey(Puv, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assignment_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This will not be enforced by the database, but will be checked by a `ModelForm`, and by the `ModelAdmin`.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Worked like magic! Thank you! Can I have more than one condition to limit_choices_to? For instance limit it to unassigned drivers? After of course adding a field is_assigned to my Users model.

Comment: @Allen: you can work with `limit_choices_to={'is_driver': True, 'is_assigned': False}`, but you do not need to make an extra field for that. You can work with a JOIN on the `Assignment`, so: `limit_choices_to={'is_driver': True, 'assignment': None}`.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! But I think there is still a need for that is_assigned field because later on driver can be unsassigned but the assigment record should stay for logs purposes I guess.

Comment: @Allen: no normally not, the joining will automatically determine if the driver is assigned. This is also more robust since if you later unassign the driver, or the vehicle is removed, it is back available.

Comment: I'm little bit confused here. Wouldn't there be a duplicate when you reassign the driver or vehicle? Or does Django has a way to go around it? Sorry I'm fairly new to Django and in my mind I would just set the is_assigned = False and then the driver or vehicle will be available again for assignment. Can you walk me through or should I post another question? Thanks!

Comment: @Allen: what I mean is that if you *remove* the `Assignment`, or the `Puv` (and thus it will also remove the `Assignment` as a `CASCADE`), then it will again be available.